# Cloudflare over https without port 443 on server

Tags: apache, ssl, cloudflare

i got a problem with my hosting provider (Mittwald) and Cloudflare.

Over Cloudflare i wanna use the flexible SSL

Cloudflare says:

> Flexible SSL: There is an encrypted connection between your website visitors and CloudFlare, but not from CloudFlare to your server.

So if i understand it right, thats exactly what i want!

The User accesses the website over https://example.com but cloudflare is communication with my site over http://example.com so that the not opened port (443) from my provider is not needed?

unfortunately that doesn't work till now... i allways get an error like

> err_connection_refused

Any help or hint would be great!

thanks in advance!

Comment: to clarify, does CloudFlare work for you with SSL off, and you get the err_connection_refused error only when enabling Flexible SSL?

Answer (score 0):

That would indicate your site hasn't yet propagated to go through CloudFlare's DNS and is pointing to your local site (where the port is closed and the connection is refused). If SSL is disabled on CloudFlare you would get a protocol error instead.

Therefore the best option would be, if you've waited for the DNS to propagate, to contact CloudFlare support.